# Show cURL response in XML

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am getting a response of SOAP API, and the response have header, body, status etc. I want to get the status from the response. Though response is in xml format, when I echo the response, it is showing on one line without xml tags.
When I use below, it shows with xml format:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($response, true));
echo '</pre>';
```

Now I want to get Status from this xml.
I am doing it as below, but not getting anything

```
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
foreach($oXML as $oEntry){
    echo $oEntry->status . "\n";echo "in foreach";
if ($oEntry->status == "Failure"){echo "Failed";}
else echo "success";
}
```

And like this as well

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response); 
print_r($xml);
```

How to get the status? Status is 'Success' or 'failure'

xml response is:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope....>
    <soapenv:Header>
       .
       .
       .
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <ns2:addOrganisationResponse ....>
       .
       .
       .
          <ns1:status>Success</ns1:status>
       </ns2:addOrganisationResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked 6 months ago but maybe this answer helps somebody.

```java
$response = curl_exec($soap_do);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($soap_do,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$result['header'] = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$result['body'] = substr($response, $header_size);
$xmlStr = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $result['body']);
$resultXml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
$xmlArray = (json_decode(json_encode($resultXml),true));
$status = $xmlArray ['soapenvBody']['ns2addOrganisationResponse']['ns1status'];
```